# Displays the result many times in Mulitselect Listbox Search in VB6

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I am creating a program in vb6 with ms access. while i am searching the database from multi select list box in vb it displays the results wrongly.

if i click the first item it shows one time
if i click second item it shows that item two times
it i click third item it shows that item three times.

how to solve this

i tried the below code

```
 For i = List1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
     If List1.Selected(i) = True Then
         If str <> "" Then str = str & ""

             If Val(List1.SelCount) = 1 Then
                 str = List1.List(List1.ListIndex)
             Else
                 str = str & " or name= " & List1.List(List1.ListIndex)
             End If
     End If
 Next i

 If str <> "" Then
     Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from Customers where name= '" & str & "'")
     display
 End If
```

result

```
 Kumar vasanth vasanth kannan kannan kannan
```

Comment: Does VB6 have SelectedItems property like VBA and vb.net? if so, instead of looping through all items in listbox just loop through its SelectedItems. How can you use `=` for multiple selected names?

Comment: Never mind about second question. I see now you are concatenating field name with each loop but that does not show in the 'result'. Could instead build a comma separated list and use IN(). `WHERE [name] IN(" & str & ")"`. Have you step debugged?

Comment: Even if your code worked like you wanted, the SQL would not be valid because of it not being correctly delimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim str As String

   For i = List1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
      If List1.Selected(i) Then str = str & " or name = '" & List1.List(i) & "'"
   Next i

   str = Mid(str, 4)

   If str <> "" Then
      Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("select * from Customers where " & str)
      display
   End If
End Sub
```